# How to convert h5 file to image?? h5topng not working?

Tags: command-line, meep

i tried h5topng to convert h5 file to png in meep but the command is giving error. how to correct this and is there any other command to convert h5 to image?
meep> h5topng -S3 eps-000000.00.h5

ERROR: Unbound variable: -S3
ABORT: (unbound-variable)
ERROR: Unbound variable: eps-000000.00.h5
ABORT: (unbound-variable)
meep>

i am unable to attach the file as link

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the error message. And provide a h5 file as link ;)

Comment: Please show the error message.

Comment: Based on the error message it sounds like you are trying to run the `h5topng` tool from inside `meep`: almost certainly, you should be running it in your normal command shell

Comment: in normal command shell also the command is not working

Answer (score 1):

h5topng is a stand-alone program and you should be executing that command from the shell prompt, not from within meep (the meep> prompt). (At the meep prompt it is expecting Scheme code.)

Answer (score 0):

Yo,
  I have been getting this error since installing meep and the problem resides in two different versions of hdf5 existing on your computer.  A quick work around is to download hdfview: https://www.hdfgroup.org/products/java/hdfview/

Locate your output file using mdfind (I'm assuming you're working on a Mac).  Open said file in HDFView then right click on the dataset within the tree and go to "open as."  Within the window, open the file as an image and BOOM done.

Cheers.